# QDialog - Change default flags to exclude ? button

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

By default, `QDialog` applies a flag (I'm not exactly sure which) that makes a question mark button appear in the top-right. I have a class `Login` which inherits from `QDialog` that I was able to get rid of this question mark button by explicitly passing a more minimal set of flags like such

```
Login::Login(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent, Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint), ui(new Ui::Login) {}
```

However, I also use other dialogs in my program, such as `QMessageBox` and `QInputDialog`.

So my question: What are all of the default flags `QDialog` uses, and is there a way I can set the default so I don't have to pass flags on my own (vulnerable to perhaps omit some that are important for cross-platform ability) **every** time I initialize a new `QDialog`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
Login::Login(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent, QDialog( ).windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint ), ui(new Ui::Login) {}
```

`~` is the bit negation operator.

`windowFlags()` contains the default flags of `QDialog`.

The same works for different flags as well so you don't modify flags you don't want to.

You asked about the default flags:

```
QFlags(0x1|0x2|0x1000|0x2000|0x10000|0x8000000)
```

---

To create a default you could make a global variable containing the WindowFlags you prefer.

For example:

```
QFlags< Qt::WindowFlags > defaultFlags;

defaultFlags = QDialog( ).windowFlags( );

defaultFlags = defaultFlags & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint;
```

Now whenever you create a Dialog for example you can pass the defaultFlags as second argument.

---

Alternatively you could just write a wrapper around the `QDialog` Class which you can then fully modify to your liking and use it without having the need to add extra parameters or to repeat yourself:

```
class CustomDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CustomDialog( QWidget *parent = 0);

};
```

Comment: I see. How about changing the default, so I don't have to type/copy paste the negation operation for each other instance I call?

Comment: This thought had crossed my mind. I was hoping for something that would actually update the default, but this may not be possible (don't know if Qt has a method to expose that or not). If you can confirm such a method isn't exposed, or if no better answer shows up in 24 hours I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Assimilater I doubt that it's possible least I wouldn't know how, but different solution would be to just write a wrapper around the QDialog which you can fully modify to your liking. At least that's how I would do it

Comment: Ya, though that doesn't help `QMessageBox`, `QLineEdit` or any of the other dialog templates.

Comment: I meant `QInputDialog` not `QLineEdit` (still new to qt and it's showing, haha)

Comment: @Assimilater You can't change the default values without modifying the source code. Your best option is to use helper functions for creating your dialogs where you set the flags you want.

Comment: @Assimilater you can also create a wrapper to wrap QInputDialog + QLineEdit in

Comment: Guess that's what I'll do then. Thanks guys :)